# sql : how can i execute two dependents queries?

Tags: java, sql

I have 2 tables (table1, table2)  table1 has a field id and table2 has a field id_eid that reference the id field of table1 as foreign key.

I have to delete from table1 all the rows that match a determinated criteria and then if these data are referenced in table2 delete the data from it too.

I do something like that, assuming `con` is the Connection object and autocommit is set to false on it.

```
    String query1 = "delete from table2 where exists 
(select * from table1 where someparameter = ? and table1.id = table2.id_eid)"
```

then i execute the first query1 using PreparedStatement.

then i have

```
    String query2 = "delete from table1 where someparameter = ? 
and exists (select * from table2 where table1.id = table2.id_eid)"
```

and i executed this with another PreparedStatment.

at the end i have the `con.commit()`.

This doesn't work, i was thinking using autocommit to false the two queries was executed together but it is not, the second query deletes no rows,  how can i do this ?

An important note, not all the rows in table1 have a referenced row in table2.

Thanks

Comment: why don't you fix your SQL table definitions? You can use foreign keys on table 2, so if something deleted from table1, database deletes the related entries on table2.

Comment: @tartar do you mean altering table adding an ON DELETE CASCADE ? i can't modify the tables

Comment: when you delete the item with id on table 1 already, will the second part of second query ever hold? (select * from table2 where table1.id = table2.id_eid)"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could always query the data to delete first, then delete it second:

1) `Select ID from table1 where <criteria>`

2) `Select ID from table2 where <criteria>`

3) `Delete from table1 where ID in <results from (1)>`

4) `Delete from table2 where ID in <results from (2)>`

Answer (score 0):

If you 
"have to delete from table1 all the rows that match a determinated criteria"
I think  String query2 must be

```
 String query2 = "delete from table1 where someparameter = ?"
```